# married couples seated on round table

Tags: probability

If 10 married couples are seated at random on a round table , then what could be the probability of no wife get seated next to her husband .

I thought of making combination . But not able to do that or anything else .

Comment: My comment on [an answer to another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/68551/6460) might suggest  something like  $\dfrac{ 2^0{5 \choose 0} 9! - 2^1{5 \choose 1} 8! + 2^2{5 \choose 2} 7! - 2^3{5 \choose 3}  6! + 2^4{5 \choose 4} 5!- 2^3{5 \choose 5}  4! }{9!}$ for a round table

Comment: @Henry could you please explain me each term

Comment: @Henry there are 10 married couples not 5 married couples

Comment: Fair enough.  For $n=10$ use inclusion-exclusion to calculate $\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)!}{\sum_{m=0}^n (-2)^m {n \choose m}(2n-1-m)!}$  which is about $0.3395$.  The limit as $n$ increases is likely to be close to $e^{-1}\approx 0.367879$